# How to make javascript function appear and play on site that i cannot change

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

Here is the code that i would want to play on one page, imgur in particular, this will click the next button in the gallery i was wondering if i would just have to make my own extension or what

```
function timeMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
}
function alertMsg()
{
alert("Hello");
}
```

Comment: okay i started making a google chrome ext but i was desgining and planning with firefox's firebug and this code would work: document.images[2].click() but when i try it in the google chrome ext it tells me that "#<HTMLImageElement> has no method 'click'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the way of chrome extensions, or greasemonkey scripts, its really comes down to you not 'doing this on the site' but manipulating your DOM in your browser.

**Greasemonkey** -- http://www.greasespot.net/
**Chrome Extensions** -- http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html

Answer (score 1):

A Chrome extension is probably your best bet. They're really easy to make.

Of course, you can always just paste that code into the console and hit Enter.

Comment: yeah but i want something that would be there and right now i'm on a firefox kick and was wondering if there was any easy way to do it, from what i've seen it doesn't look like it

Comment: Well, if you want the easiest possible solution, you could write a bookmarklet. You'll have the extra step of clicking the bookmark, but you won't have to write a greasemonkey or chrome extension (although both of those things are pretty easy in their own right).

Comment: @Icallitvera, the easiest way might be to email the owners of imgur and see if they like your mod to make usage easier ;) Otherwise you need to do one of the things kennis and I suggested (there are others too, like firefox plugins / extensions).

Answer (score 0):

I have to use an online time clock for work.  I made a bookmarklet that populates the form and submits it.  It isn't running on their site, just fiddling with the DOM.

- Test your javascript on their site using the developer console
- Save a bookmark of the page
- edit the newly created bookmark in the bookmark manager and change the URL to something like this

> > javscript:( your function )();

[example](http://mcottondesign3.appspot.com/post/ag5tY290dG9uZGVzaWduM3IMCxIEQmxvZxji8QoM)